# Why is necessary two requests to transfer the file?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this method below to download a file from an API server. But its not working properly, when the user clicks in the button that calls the getFile() method it appears at first in the page the error

> Trying to get property of non-object

But if the user click in the browser refresh button the file is downloaded.

So it seems that for the file be generated is necessary send two requests and in the first appears

> Trying to get property of non-object

In the second the file is transfered, in the third it appears again

> Trying to get property of non-object

In the API says that to download the file is an asynchronous operation, which means that the file may not be ready immediately. I dont know if the issue can be because of that.

Code:

```
 public function getFile($regId){
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $user = Auth::user();

        $registration = $user->registrations()->with(["proforma"])->where("id", $regId)->first();
        $proforma = $registration->proforma->proforma_number;

        $getProforma = $client->request('GET', 'https://...'.$proforma.'.json', [
            'query' => ['api_key' => '...'],
        ]);
        $response = $getProforma->getBody()->getContents();

        $url = null;
        if(!empty($response)) {
            $response = json_decode($response);

            $url = !empty($response->output->pdfUrl) ? $response->output->pdfUrl : '';
        }
        header("Location: $url");
    }
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: Can you show all the error message please and identify the line in the code

Comment: Thanks, the error is "ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object" in "            $url = $response->output->pdfUrl;
". But to show that error the code dont have the "        if(!empty($response)) {" part , its just with the " $response = json_decode($response);

            $url = $response->output->pdfUrl;" With that part "        if(!empty($response)) {" it shows a blank page in the first request and after refresh  it transfers the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getFile($regId)
{
    $registration = auth()->user()->registrations()->with(["proforma"])->where("id", $regId)->first();
    $proforma = $registration->proforma->proforma_number;

    $getProforma = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://...' . $proforma . '.json?api_key=.....'));
    // $getProforma->output here was your problem so I advice you to: dd($getProforma);
    $url = ! empty(optional($getProforma->output)->pdfUrl) ? optional($getProforma->output)->pdfUrl : '/'; // it will redict home if it couldn't find the PDF URL

    return redirect($url);
}
```